# Improving a selection routine

Tags: list-manipulation

How can this code for extracting the smallest (absolute) real value be improved?  and would it be simpler using associations?

```
results = {{sf -> -8233.0746}, {sf -> -3027.5805}, {sf -> -2669.9484},
   {sf -> -532.5415 + 179.08778 I}, {sf -> -324.8825 + 224.3397 I},
   {sf -> -324.8825 - 224.3397 I}, {sf -> -0.0559 + 0.1234 I}, {sf -> 390.8250},
   {sf -> 449.5389}, {sf -> 555.6940}, {sf -> 705.9079}, {sf -> 765.9997},
   {sf -> 1179.2476}, {sf -> 9.005559*^15}, {sf -> 9.005647*^15},
   {sf -> 9.007284*^15}, {sf -> 9.009280*^15}};

realresults = Extract[results, Position[results[[All, 1, 2]], _Real]];

min = Extract[realresults,
  Position[Abs@realresults[[All, 1, 2]], Min[Abs@realresults[[All, 1, 2]]]]]
```

> {{sf -> 390.825}}

***Edit*** A method to preserve the rule would be great, for instance if the data is:

```
results = {{a -> -8233.0746}, {b -> -3027.5805}, {c -> -2669.9484}, ...
```

Comment: Something like `MinimalBy[Abs]@Select[Im[#] == 0 &]@Replace[results]@sf`?  Do you need to keep `sf -> ...`?  `_Real` won't match `1 + 0. I`, so I used `Im[#] == 0&` instead.  You may want to stick a `First@...` at the beginning, note that `MinimalBy` may return more than one result, `MinimalBy[{1,-1,2}, Abs]` --> `{1,-1}`.

Comment: @Szabolcs - Interesting, I didn't know `MinimalBy`.  Thanks.  I meant to keep the rule intact, but the question as posted didn't require it.

Comment: Regarding the question about associations: most things that work on associations also work on rule lists.  So if we already had filtered the reals (e.g. using the domain in NSolve) then this would be easy: `results // MinimalBy[Values /* Abs]`.

Comment: If you have multiple rules, are the LHS the same for all, or are there repetitions?  I.e. can we have `{a->1, b->2, a->3}`, where `a` repeats?

Comment: @Szabolcs - yes, I would have repetitions.  Michael E2's answer works for any mix of lhs's.  (Thanks for your deleted answer, btw.  I'll be checking out the postfix style. )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is arguably "simpler":

```
Nearest[Cases[results, _Real, Infinity], 0]
(*  {390.825}  *)
```

---

In case the rule matters, the above is easily adapted:

```
Nearest[Cases[results, r : {_ -> x_Real} :> x -> r], 0]
(*  {{sf -> 390.825}}  *)
```

Comment: @Chris You tricked me by changing `results` just as I was about to post...but I caught it.  :)  -- Just noticed, you didn't extract the real value but the rule.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Trying to extract the rule intact is more of a challenge, and would be relevant if the *lhs* varied.  As it is, dispensing with the rule is an retrospectively obvious efficiency. ;-)

Comment: + 1 Both really informative solutions, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps not as clean as Michael's but I still like it:

```
results // Cases[{_ -> _Real}] // MinimalBy[Abs@*Values]
```

> ```
> {{sf -> 390.825}}
> ```

Comment: +1 Lol. What is going on with `MinimalBy[Abs@*Values]` !?

Comment: @Chris I am uncertain how to interpret that comment.  It is an operator form of `MinimalBy` using a `Composition` of two functions, `Abs`, and `Values`.  This takes version 10 or later.  What are you running?

Comment: I'm running version 10.  I looked up `@*` in the docs but nothing came up.  Found it via `Composition`.  Thanks.  Very interesting answer.

Comment: @Chris Okay. :-)  Weird looking code I admit.

Comment: Neat ! Operator form + Composition + Values. It certainly is more compact and more readable than `...// MinimalBy[#, Abs[#[[1, 2]]] &] &`

Answer (score 5):

Not really better but might be interesting:

For versions >= 10.1

```
(* EDIT: previous definition: *)
(* f[x_] := Abs@x
   f[x_Complex] := Null *)

f[x_Real] := Abs@x
f[x_] := Null
```

then

```
TakeSmallestBy[results, f@*Values@*First, 1]
(*TakeSmallestBy[results, f[Values[First[#]]] &, 1]*)
```

> `{{sf -> 390.825}}`

**Explanation**:

`TakeSmallestBy`can deal with exceptions by just dropping them from the list.

[image]

Comment: Of course I stole the composition nice idea from @Mr.Wizard answer.

Comment: +1 Another interesting function revealed --`TakeSmallestBy`

Answer (score 3):

Of course it depends on what you deem simpler, but here is my attempt that retains the transformation rule structure in the output, since you mention it in your question:

```
First@SortBy[Select[results, Im[sf /. #] == 0 &], Abs[sf] /. # &]

(* Out: {sf -> 390.825} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because Chris also asked about `Association`s:

```
asc = AssociationThread[CharacterRange["a", "q"] -> results[[All, 1, 2]]]
```

`TakeSmallestBy` works perfectly with associations:

```
TakeSmallestBy[asc, Abs, 1]
```

[image]

To also get position and (absolute) value:

```
TakeSmallestBy[asc -> {"Index", "Element", "Value"}, Abs, 1]
```

[image]

Restrict selection to Reals:

```
TakeSmallestBy[Select[RealValuedNumberQ] @ asc, Abs, 1]
```

[image]

The two smallest elements (converted to `List`):

```
Normal @ TakeSmallestBy[Select[RealValuedNumberQ] @ asc, Abs, 2]
```

{"h" -> 390.825, "i" -> 449.539}

`RealValuedNumberQ` came with V 13.3

Answer (score 2):

Using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
asc = AssociationThread[CharacterRange["a", "q"] -> results[[All, 1, 2]]]

GroupBy[asc, RealValuedNumberQ, MinimalBy[#, Abs] &][True]

<|"h" -> 390.825|>
```